# Flutter trying to install after install

Tags: flutter

Here is what i get after typing in flutter. Tried snap and it doesn't work. I don't like my Linux to be sloppy. So I am not going to download the raw and put it somewhere random in my machine. I want to do it right. Not have a hack job of an install. Here is what i get after following advice on this sites advice.

So far no method recommended on this site has worked from stackoverflow. Not even sudo snap remove flutter, sudo snap install flutter --classic. Its the same thing for any flutter command.

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRYcV.png)
https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_2.2.1-stable.tar.xz

Comment: Your question is wrongly formulated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The flutter official documentation explain correctly how to install flutter on Linux.

Just follow the "Install Flutter manually": https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux

(By the way, please put a better title for your question)